# Microsoft sync framework 2.1 large data returns connection timeout

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Hi i am trying to **sync 3 tables with 2 databases** on different servers.

The tables is **kind of large** with a total of 5029513 rows, the data size is 1,45gb:

When i try syncing client & server with empty table data it **succeeds**, so there is nothing wrong with the connection.

I have tried to leave the script running over night with Command Timeout set to 36000 seconds, but when i wake up i get a **Connection timeout exception**.

**Stacktrace:**

```
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   vid System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   vid Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncTrackingTableHelper.PopulateFromBaseTable(SqlTransaction trans)
   vid Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncTableProvisioning.Apply(SqlTransaction trans)
   vid Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.ApplyScope(SqlConnection connection)
   vid Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.ApplyInternal(SqlConnection connection)
   vid Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.Apply()
   vid itsperfect.ResponseHandler.Syncronization.Program.Main() i c:\Dev\TFS\itsperfect\Web\ResponseHandler\Main\src\itsperfectResponseHandler\itsperfect.ResponseHandler.Syncronization.Test\Program.cs:rad 45
   vid System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   vid System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   vid System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   vid System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   vid System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

What can i do to make this work? **The Client is** 'SQL Server 2008' And the **Server is** 'SQL Server 2005 SP3'

This is the code i am using and it **stops at serverProvision.Apply()**:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //setup scope name
            const string scopeName = "EmailSyncDBScope";

            //setup the connections
            var serverConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServerConnection"].ConnectionString);
            var clientConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientConnection"].ConnectionString);
            var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);

            serverProvision.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SyncCommandTimeout"));

            //provision server
            if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                var serverScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                // add table
                var emailTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Email", serverConn);
                var emailMessageTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Email_Message", serverConn);
                var emailStatusTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Email_Status", serverConn);

                serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(emailTableDesc);
                serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(emailMessageTableDesc);
                serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(emailStatusTableDesc);

                serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(serverScopeDesc);
                //apply the scope definition

                Console.WriteLine("Applying server provision.");
                serverProvision.Apply();
            }

            //provision client
            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn);
            clientProvision.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SyncCommandTimeout"));

            if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                //get scope description from server
                var scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(scopeName, serverConn);
                clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
                //apply the scope definition
                Console.WriteLine("Applying client provision.");
                clientProvision.Apply();
            }

            // create the sync orchestrator
            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            //setup providers
            var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, clientConn);
            var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, serverConn);
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;

            Console.WriteLine("Getting sync direction order settings.");
            var syncDirectionOrder = GetSyncDirectionOrder(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SyncDirectionOrder"));

            // set sync direction
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = syncDirectionOrder;

            // execute the synchronization process
            SyncAndEmail(syncOrchestrator, bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SendMail")));

        }

        private static SyncDirectionOrder GetSyncDirectionOrder(string syncDirectionOrder)
        {
            SyncDirectionOrder returnValue;

            switch (syncDirectionOrder)
            {
                case "Upload" :
                    returnValue = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
                    break;
                case "Download" :
                    returnValue = SyncDirectionOrder.Download;
                    break;
                case "UploadAndDownload" :
                    returnValue = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
                    break;
                case "DownloadAndUpload" :
                    returnValue = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;
                    break;
                default:
                    returnValue = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
                    break;
            }

            return returnValue;
        }

        private static void SyncAndEmail(SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator, bool sendEmail)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Syncronizing.");
            var syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            var content = new StringBuilder();
            content.Append("<p><h2>Syncronization report:</h2></p>");
            content.Append("<strong>Start Time:</strong> " + syncStats.SyncStartTime + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Uploaded:</strong> " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Uploaded and Applied:</strong> " + syncStats.UploadChangesApplied + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Uploaded and Failed:</strong> " + syncStats.UploadChangesFailed + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Downloaded:</strong> " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Downloaded and Applied:</strong> " + syncStats.DownloadChangesApplied + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Total Changes Downloaded and Failed:</strong> " + syncStats.DownloadChangesFailed + "</br>");
            content.Append("<strong>Complete Time:</strong> " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);

        if (sendEmail)
            {
                var emailModel = new EmailModel
                {
                    MailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MailTo").ToLower(),
                    MailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MailFrom").ToLower(),
                    Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MailSubject"),
                    Content = content.ToString()
                };

                var mailClient = new MailServiceClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Sending email.");
                mailClient.SendFromExtreme(emailModel.MailFrom, new[] { emailModel.MailTo }, emailModel.Subject, emailModel.Content, "", new[] { "Syncronization" }, EmailType.ControlTask, 0, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CommandTimeout on the SqlCommand directly.

Read more here,[Sync framework TimeOut](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76928573-797e-46a6-94d0-38c41241f84d/sync-framework-timeout-expired?forum=syncdevdiscussions)

Comment: I have set the CommandTimeout on the SqlSyncScopeProvisioning to 36000 . And that works, do you think i need more time?

I also notice that the sync framework creates a reference in Email_tracking for every post there is. Is that so smart? My Db gets the double amount of rows.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the entry on the tracking tables is not a duplicate copy of the rows from the tables you're synching. It's the PK plus filter columns and other Sync Fx metadata. The framework needs to record that a row was inserted/updated/deleted from which replica.